# implement itext html2pdf in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, itext

what implementation should be put in the build.gradle file to import the html2pdf library (itext7 extention)?

I'm trying to convert html to pdf using itext7 through android studio.
For that purpose I need the HtmlConverter class (https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/java/2.1.6/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/HtmlConverter.html) from the html2pdf library but i can't seem to find how to implement it in my project.

That's the function i'm trying to use:

```
public void createPdf(URL url, String dest) throws IOException {
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(url.openStream(), new FileOutputStream(dest));
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: changed it hope its better. basically asking how to implement html2pdf (the itext7 extention) in my project so i can use it's classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the repository from maven central
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.android